# Cassandra CQL query for unique id which is not a key

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

I have the following table

```
 create table Table (
 timestamp bigint,
 topic text,
 page text,
 visits int,
 client_id text,
 PRIMARY KEY ((topic, timestamp), visits)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(visits DESC);
```

Now the table schema is flexible. I'm new to Cassandra. And I want to be able to select the pages with the most unique client visits, but I'm not sure how to do this is a CQL query.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: This kinds of job is done by Spark or Hadoop.

Comment: Adding some example will make it more clear that what exactly you want to fetch .

Answer (score 0):

Your partition key is topic and timestamp. Which is problematic because each topic and timestamp combination will be a new partition.
And visits is the clustering key, also part of the primary key, then anytime you update the visits, you will create a new row. Is this what you wanted?

In Cassandra, the model should comply to your query. And your partition key should be carefully picked. And select pages with most unique users, it is very hard to pick your partition key, because the count is changing all the time.

[How to model cassandra model](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling)